# Using Laravel Blade templates with Vue JS and event listeners

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am using Laraval custom components, for example, I have:

**components/input.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" class="rounded">
```

Note: this is a simple example, the key part here is that I want to reuse the HTML generated by the blade template.

Now I can create a Vue component with a scoped slot:

**js/components/Search.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="search-input" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      focus() {
        console.log('focus input');
      }
    }
  }
</script>

// ... and registering the component
// among others 

Vue.component('search', require('js/components/Search'));
new Vue({
  el: '#vue_app'
});
```

Now great, I can use my component as follows:

**views/somepage.blade.php**

```
<search>
  <template v-slot:search>
    <x-input>
  </template>
</search>
```

All works as expected, however as you can see I have a `focus` method, which I would like to be triggered when focusing on the blade input.

Now I can't do this:

**js/components/Search.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="search-input" @focus="focus" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      focus() {
        console.log('focus input');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I can do this:

**js/components/Search.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="search-container"><slot name="search-input" /></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      mounted() {
          this.$refs['search-container'].querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', this.focus)
      },
      focus() {
        console.log('focus input');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I am not sure that using `addEventListener` is the best approach within a Vue component.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: So in the second part you are mounting it and directly accessing the input field which is actually part of component that's why it would work. So are you trying to get the focus on page render itself?

Comment: @Adi, it works as expected, however, I am just questioning if this is best practice. It feels like a bit of a workaround to me. Normally I would bind a click listener by `<a @click="doSomething()">` and it would be nice to have a similar way to bind to elements contained within a slot.

Comment: Prefer using `<a @click="doSomething">` if you don't want the function to run at initial render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred solution was to utilise [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) and their slot props to pass methods. An end solution would look like:

**views/somepage.blade.php**

```
<search>
  <template v-slot:default>
    <x-input @focus="slot.methods.focus">
  </template>
</search>
```

You can see above I am referencing the slot props variable `slot` to access the variables that I define below. Notice I pass a `methods` object. Calling the object `methods` is just a preference of mine. I decided to add both `methods` and `props` when necessary.

**js/components/Search.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :methods="{ focus }" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      focus() {
        console.log('focus input');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly of the issue, maybe

```js
this.$refs['search-container'].querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', this.focus)
```

is somehow *async* (lifecycle-wise) and that you may need to wrap it into a [`nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs['search-container'].querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', this.focus)
})
```

Btw, IMO there is no issue with this way of adding a listener.

Also, maybe try `@focus.native="focus"` as suggested here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components
Because maybe of hydration, it may take some time for the element to be available as a Vue node, so sticking it a native focus may be the solution.

Not sure that those may work but those are the 2 ideas that I have.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess the consensus will be that adding the event listener in this way is ok. The code in my example works as expected. I am just questioning the style of adding event listeners. As I am sure this must be a common problem run into by wanting to use styled Blade components within Vue templates and binding events to them

Comment: As told above, it looks fine for me. :D

Comment: Not sure if I am on the right track here but can't you pass your event handler @click to a blade component using the attribute bag?

Comment: @futureweb I guess that would be along the right lines, but I don't know if the component would have the right context to trigger the correct method.